# typescript - is there a way to create an instance from type definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, serialization, types

Using Typescript, I am trying to create a DI system, and I want to use the `type` (or `interface`) as the key.

For example,

```
interface IMath {
  add: (a: number, b: number) => number;
  sub: (a: number, b: number) => number;
}
```

```
class Math implements IMath {
  add(a: number, b: number) { return a + b };
  sub(a: number, b: number) { return a - b };
}
```

```
di.register(IMath, Math); // of course this doesn't work
```

This is is possible in runtime-typed languages, like C#, where types are in-memory (which we don't want).
In typescript, all type data is removed before ever reaching runtime.

My question is - can we create an object or symbol, that will represent the type during runtime?

```
const mathId = typeToId<IMath>();
// "c8393b569dbae9ed04e5b22d9c2e6fb7"
```

```
const mathStub = typeToStub<IMath>();
// { add: () => 0, sub: () => 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar project I found was [flow-runtime](https://github.com/gajus/flow-runtime), using [babel-plugin-flow-runtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-flow-runtime). (There's also a TS equivalent called TS-runtime, but it doesn't seem as developed)

```
type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};
```

transforms into

```
import t from 'flow-runtime';
const User = t.type('User', t.object(
  t.property('id', t.number()),
  t.property('name', t.string())
));
```

This seems like an overkill, both in bundle size and performance.
I also tried it in one of my projects still using Flow, and it's giving mixed results.